# jQuery not defined after Drupal update

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

After updating drupal core from 7.65 to 7.67 all js (slicks, etc) on my website is not working, in console I have some errors of kind:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at
>   js_Day36PImT2OzbiUMu1I39TozbeHYo7FH6Utc194C6K0.js:120

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem after updating to 7.67. Some javascript is working, but I'm getting "Drupal is not defined". Disabling "aggregate Javascript files" in /admin/config/development/performance fixes the issue for me, but I'd like to figure out the root of it.

Googling tells me the issue could be my /misc/drupal.js file, but it loads in my browser fine.

Comment: @ChrisBauer, I solved my problem, but I don't remember how, it was 7 months ago, I even don't remember which project it was :( But I remember that the answer was quite ridiculous... Good luck!

Comment: For me the issue ended up being that the 'secure pages' module was enabled on my development site, which forces are hardcoded url to the live site. I believe this caused javascript loading issues and gave me the error. I fixed it by disabling the module and then javascript loaded correctly.